# PPPD refuse to work with Sierra : HL7690

Tags: linux-networking, modem, point-to-point-protocol

I am trying to get a working connection with PPPD in 4G with Sierra HL7690.

Every time I launch PPPD I get a either a "NO CARRIER" or a Modem hangup.

The sequence I use is the following :

Reset the modem
Set the context : AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.sierrawireless.com"
Wait until the system is registered
Launch pppd with the following parameters :

```
pppd /dev/ttyACM2 115200 debug kdebug 1 nodetach noauth defaultroute usepeerdns deflate 15 noipx nomagic nopcomp noaccomp connect 'chat -v "ABORT" "BUSY" "ABORT" "NO CARRIER" "ABORT" "ERROR" "" "ATZ" "OK" "AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"internet.sierrawireless.com\"" "OK" "ATDT*99***1#" "CONNECT"'*
```

And I get this logs in results :

```
Apr 26 13:21:07 sdn-ip-spt daemon.info pppd[1407]: Serial connection established.
Apr 26 13:21:07 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: using channel 3
Apr 26 13:21:07 sdn-ip-spt daemon.info pppd[1407]: Using interface ppp0
Apr 26 13:21:07 sdn-ip-spt daemon.notice pppd[1407]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyACM2
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <lcp>  01 01 00 0a 02 06 00 00 00 00
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0>]
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <lcp>  01 01 00 14 02 06 00 00 00 00 05 06 86 02 da 91 07 02 08 02
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x8602da91> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <lcp>  04 01 00 0e 05 06 86 02 da 91 07 02 08 02
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <magic 0x8602da91> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <lcp>  02 01 00 0a 02 06 00 00 00 00
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0>]
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <lcp>  01 02 00 0a 02 06 00 00 00 00
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0>]
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <lcp>  02 02 00 0a 02 06 00 00 00 00
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0>]
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <ccp>  01 01 00 0f 1a 04 78 00 18 04 78 00 15 03 2f
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15> <bsd v1 15>]
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <ipcp>  01 01 00 1c 02 06 00 2d 0f 01 03 06 00 00 00 00 81 06 00 00 00 00 83 06 00 00 00 00
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <lcp>  08 03 00 13 80 fd 80 fd 01 01 00 0f 1a 04 78 00 18 04 78
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x3 80 fd 80 fd 01 01 00 0f 1a 04 78 00 18 04 78]
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: Protocol-Reject for 'Compression Control Protocol' (0x80fd) received
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <ipcp>  01 01 00 04
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1]
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <ipcp>  03 01 00 0a 03 06 00 00 00 00
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <ipcp>  04 01 00 10 02 06 00 2d 0f 01 03 06 00 00 00 00
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <ipcp>  01 02 00 1a 01 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 81 06 00 00 00 00 83 06 00 00 00 00
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addrs 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <ipcp>  01 02 00 04
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2]
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <ipcp>  02 02 00 04
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x2]
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <ipcp>  04 02 00 0e 01 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x2 <addrs 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0>]
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <ipcp>  01 03 00 10 81 06 00 00 00 00 83 06 00 00 00 00
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <ipcp>  03 03 00 10 81 06 08 08 08 08 83 06 04 02 02 02
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x3 <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 4.2.2.2>]
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]:    <ipcp>  01 04 00 10 81 06 08 08 08 08 83 06 04 02 02 02
Apr 26 13:21:08 sdn-ip-spt daemon.debug pppd[1407]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x4 <ms-dns1 8.8.8.8> <ms-dns2 4.2.2.2>]
Apr 26 13:21:09 sdn-ip-spt daemon.notice pppd[1407]: Modem hangup
Apr 26 13:21:09 sdn-ip-spt daemon.notice pppd[1407]: Connection terminated.
Apr 26 13:21:10 sdn-ip-spt daemon.info pppd[1407]: Exit.
Linux: Linux sdn-ip-spt 3.14.49
```

pppd configuration (from dump command)

```
debug       # (from command line)
kdebug 1        # (from command line)
nodetach        # (from command line)
dump        # (from command line)
noauth      # (from command line)
/dev/ttyACM2        # (from command line)
115200      # (from command line)
lock        # (from /etc/ppp/options)
connect chat -v \"ABORT\" \"BUSY\" \"ABORT\" \"NO CARRIER\" \"ABORT\" \"ERROR\" \"\" \"ATZ\" \"OK\" \"OK\" \"ATDT*99***1#\" \"CONNECT\"     # (from command line)
crtscts     # (from /etc/ppp/options)
modem       # (from /etc/ppp/options)
noaccomp        # (from command line)
asyncmap 0      # (from /etc/ppp/options)
nomagic     # (from command line)
nopcomp     # (from command line)
lcp-echo-failure 4      # (from /etc/ppp/options)
lcp-echo-interval 30        # (from /etc/ppp/options)
hide-password       # (from /etc/ppp/options)
defaultroute        # (from command line)
proxyarp        # (from /etc/ppp/options)
usepeerdns      # (from command line)
deflate 15      # (from command line)
noipx       # (from command line)
```

**PPPD :** v1.4.7

**Modem :** RHL769x.2.23.172400.201706231140.x7120m_1

**SIM card :** Sierra airvantage (smart sim)

Comment: Remove the `ms-dns` entries from your `pppd` configuration.

Comment: Remove the usednspeers (now I see no ms-dns request), but the result is always the same. I suspect the problem is the IP address is not sent by the remote server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found any workaround. The tricks is to use the PDP context 2 instead of PDP context 1.

Change the command :

pppd /dev/ttyACM2 115200 debug kdebug 1 nodetach noauth defaultroute usepeerdns deflate 15 noipx nomagic nopcomp noaccomp connect 'chat -v "ABORT" "BUSY" "ABORT" "NO CARRIER" "ABORT" "ERROR" "" "ATZ" "OK" **"AT+CGDCONT=2**,\"IP\",\"internet.sierrawireless.com\"" "OK" **"ATDT*99***2#"** "CONNECT"'*

Apparently the problem come from the new method to retrieving IP address with LTE network. And the PDP context 1, is used for this feature. For some reason there is a conflict between the CHAT script and the modem I am used, and this lead to an error. The workaround with the usage of PDP context 2, avoid this conflict.